# register_setting not saving variable in wp_options

Tags: wordpress

This is my first time writing a plugin and I'm using [Wordpress Plugin Boilerplate](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/) to create necessary files.

I'm trying to add a plugin file settings but cannot make it work. In `plugin/admin/class-plugin-admin.php` I added the following codes:

```
class Plugin_Admin {
    ...
    public function update_options() {
        register_setting($this->plugin_name, $this->plugin_name, array($this, 'validate_options'));
    }

    public function validate_options() {
        // I am going to validate the input so this is just an example code
        $options = array();
        $options["api_key"] = "123456";
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Then I added them to admin hooks in `plugin/includes/class-plugin.php`

```
class Plugin {
    ...
    private function define_admin_hooks() {

        $plugin_admin = new Plugin_Admin( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );
        ...
        $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_init', $plugin_admin, 'update_options' );
    }
}
```

So when I call it with `get_option($this->plugin_name)` it is returning `string(0) ""`  with `var_dump` and I also cannot find `api_key` in the database table. So my conclusion is the code is not saving the option.

What I understand about `register_setting` is that it takes care of `add_option` part. Is there something I am missing?